# Text Scaling based on width

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I converted a PDF into an HTML using an online converter. Here's an example result:
http://www.ww2incolor.com/500px/e8efe9ed-37d4-45c4-bd12-178d9bac0947/e8efe9ed-37d4-45c4-bd12-178d9bac0947.html

It does a pretty good job, but is it possible to have it scale to 100% width to make it mobile friendly?
Getting the image to scale to 100% width is pretty easy, but the text doesn't seem to wanna scale at all. I've looked into font scaling, but that messes up the location of the text which is important. Essentially both image and text need to scale in tandem.
transform: scale(X) does what I want it to do, but the width of the PDF can change, so it's not a good solution unless you can make it dynamic. Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: There are libraries that could help with that. For example: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js to scale the page, like this:

```
var page = document.querySelector('#pf1');

var getRatio = function(elem){
    return document.body.offsetWidth / elem.offsetWidth;
};

page.style.transformOrigin = 'center top';

var applyZoom = function(){
    page.style.transform = 'scale(' + getRatio(page) + ')';
}
```

Call this on document ready, resize, and orientation change events:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => applyZoom());
window.addEventListener('resize', () => applyZoom());
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => applyZoom()); // probably not needed
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! From my understanding it happens only on load. So if I look at a page on my phone in portrait mode and then rotate it to landscape, I need to reload the page for it to work. Is there way around that?

Comment: Like I said, you'll need to handle window resize and orientationchange events. I'll update my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with the ONRESIZE event in your PDF's container:

```
<div id="PDFbox" onresize="DoScale();"></div>




 function DoScale(){

 // Get your new container dimensions...

 var W=PDFbox.outerWidth;

 var H=PDFbox.outerHeight;  

 // and then based on whatever logic you prefer, dynamically scale
 whatever is neccessary...


AnotherID.style.transform='scale(2,2)';
}
```

I hope I understood you well.